# Arbitrary precision for decimals square roots in golang

Tags: go, precision

I am looking for a way to calculate a square root with an arbitrary precision (something like 50 digits after the dot).

In python, it is easily accessible with [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html):

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 50
Decimal(2).sqrt() # and here you go my 50 digits
```

After seeing the power of `math/big` I skimmed through the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Rat) but have not found anything similar.

So is my only option is to write some sort of [numerical computing method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) which will iteratively try to compute the answer?

Comment: Is the question too bad? I do not bite and take critique properly.

Comment: you can use this:https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Rat.FloatString

Comment: @Atomic_alarm the problem is that in this case I would already need to know the answer (as your method just converts a rational to string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my own implementation of square root calculation. While waiting for answers, I decided to give [methods of computing square roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) a try. It has a whole bunch of methods but at the very end I found a link to a  [Square roots by subtraction](http://www.afjarvis.staff.shef.ac.uk/maths/jarvisspec02.pdf) pdf, which I really liked because the description of the algorithm is only a couple of lines (and I have not seen it before in comparison to Newton's method).

So here is my implementation (bigint is not really nice to work with in go):

```
func square(n int64, precision int64) string{
    ans_int := strconv.Itoa(int(math.Sqrt(float64(n))))

    limit   := new(big.Int).Exp(big.NewInt(10), big.NewInt(precision + 1), nil)
    a       := big.NewInt(5 * n)
    b       := big.NewInt(5)
    five    := big.NewInt(5)
    ten     := big.NewInt(10)
    hundred := big.NewInt(100)

    for b.Cmp(limit) < 0{
        if a.Cmp(b) < 0{
                a.Mul(a, hundred)
            tmp := new(big.Int).Div(b, ten)
            tmp.Mul(tmp, hundred)
            b.Add(tmp, five)
        } else {
            a.Sub(a, b)
            b.Add(b, ten)
        }
    }
    b.Div(b, hundred)

    ans_dec := b.String()

    return ans_dec[:len(ans_int)] + "." + ans_dec[len(ans_int):]
}
```

**P.S.** thank you Nick Craig-Wood for making the code better with your amazing comment.

And using it, one can find that `square(8537341, 50)` is:

> 2921.8728582879851242173838229735693053765773170487

which is only by one last digit of from python's

```
getcontext().prec = 50
print str(Decimal(8537341).sqrt())
```

> 2921.8728582879851242173838229735693053765773170488

This one digit is off because the last digit is not really precise.

As always <kbd>[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/u1CoB4cwXy)</kbd>.

**P.S.** if someone would find a native way to do this, I would gladly give my accept and upvote.

Comment: Here are some things which will make using `math/big` a bit more natural. Instead of `b.Cmp(limit) == -1` write `b.Cmp(limit) < 0` which gives you the idea of what you are testing, ie `b < limit`.  Instead of `a = new(big.Int).Mul(a, hundred)` you can just write `a.Mul(a, hundred)` which saves making some new big ints.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood thank you for your suggestions. I will test them and update my answer.

Comment: That's awesome. [`math/big.Float`](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/math/big/) in 1.5 will get rid of the extra steps to use  ints like floats, but looks like you'll still have to write your own `sqrt` in terms of the arithmetic functions.

Answer (score 3):

### Adding precision

There is probably a solution in go but as I don't code in go, here is a general solution.

For instance if your selected language doesn't provide a solution to handle the precision of floats (already happened to me):

If your language provides you N digits after the dot, you can, in the case of the square root, multiply the input, here `2`, by `10^(2*number_of_extra_digits)`.

For instance if go would give you only `1.41` as an answer but you would want `1.4142`, then you ask it the square root of `2*10^(2*2) = 2*10000` instead and you get `141.42` as an answer. Now I leave it up to you to rectify the placement of the dot.

**Explanation:** There is some math magic behind it.

If you were to want to add some precision to a simple division, you would just need to multiply the input by `10^number_of_extra_digits`.

The trick is to multiply the input to get more precision as we can't multiply the output (the lost of precision already happened). It does work because most languages cut more decimals after the dot, than before it.

So we just need to change the *output equation* to the *input equation* (when possible):

For simple division: `(a/b) * 10 = (a*10)/b`

For square root: `sqrt(a) * 10 = sqrt(a) * sqrt(100) = sqrt(a*100)`

### Reducing precision

Some similar tinkering can also help to reduce the precision if needed.

For instance if you were trying to calculate the progression of a download in percent, two digits after the dot.

Let's say we downloaded 1 file on 3, then `1/3 * 100` would give us `33.33333333`.

If there is no way to control the precision of this float, then you could do  `cast_to_an_int(1/3 * 100 * 100) / 100` to return `33.33`.

Comment: Wow, this is actually a really nice way to double the precision +1. A couple of my tests shows that it kind of work (will try to prove this).

Comment: @SalvadorDali I added some explanation on how it works and how to proceed to find out how to add precision by yourself for some given set of operations.