# Is there a Go function for obtaining the cube root of a big integer?

Tags: algorithm, go

I have a `big.Int` variable, and wish to find the cube root of it.

Is this implemented somewhere in the library?  The Exp function seems to only take an integer, and `big.Rat` seems to be lacking Exp entirely.

Comment: let a Rat is z(=x/y), how about root(z) = root(x)/root(y)?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263087/finding-the-cube-root-of-a-number-using-integer-arithmetic-only

Answer (score 2):

Sadly but there is no such function in [math/big](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/) package. This means that you have to roll out something on your own. One of the easiest to understand and implement is the [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method).

All you need is to select some starting number `x_0` and use the recursive formula [image]

---

You have to use it in the following way: Let your integer is `b`. Then your `x^3 = b^3` and your `f(x) = x^3 - b^3` and `f'(x) = 3 * x^2`.

So you need to iterate:
`x_{n+1}=x_n - \frac{x_{n}^{3} + b^3}{3x_{n}^{2}}`

([check this link](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?x_%7Bn+1%7D%3Dx_n%20-%20%5Cfrac%7Bx_%7Bn%7D%5E%7B3%7D%20+%20b%5E3%7D%7B3x_%7Bn%7D%5E%7B2%7D%7D) with the image of the formula, SO sucks in inserting math formulas).

You start from a guess and ends when previous x_n is close to the next one. How close is for you to decide.

**P.S.1** you can look for more complicated numerical methods to find roots (you will need less iterations to converge)

**P.S.2** if you need, I wrote a [method for calculating arbitrary precision square roots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30316639/1090562) in Go.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a cube root function for `big.Int`, both using a simple binary search and Newton's method as per Salvador Dali's formula. Although I am pretty sure there is room for improvement, here is the code that I've got:

```golang
var (
    n0  = big.NewInt(0)
    n1  = big.NewInt(1)
    n2  = big.NewInt(2)
    n3  = big.NewInt(3)
    n10 = big.NewInt(10)
)

func cbrtBinary(i *big.Int) (cbrt *big.Int, rem *big.Int) {
    var (
        guess = new(big.Int).Div(i, n2)
        dx    = new(big.Int)
        absDx = new(big.Int)
        minDx = new(big.Int).Abs(i)
        step  = new(big.Int).Abs(new(big.Int).Div(guess, n2))
        cube  = new(big.Int)
    )
    for {
        cube.Exp(guess, n3, nil)
        dx.Sub(i, cube)
        cmp := dx.Cmp(n0)
        if cmp == 0 {
            return guess, n0
        }

        absDx.Abs(dx)
        switch absDx.Cmp(minDx) {
        case -1:
            minDx.Set(absDx)
        case 0:
            return guess, dx
        }

        switch cmp {
        case -1:
            guess.Sub(guess, step)
        case +1:
            guess.Add(guess, step)
        }

        step.Div(step, n2)
        if step.Cmp(n0) == 0 {
            step.Set(n1)
        }
    }
}

func cbrtNewton(i *big.Int) (cbrt *big.Int, rem *big.Int) {
    var (
        guess   = new(big.Int).Div(i, n2)
        guessSq = new(big.Int)
        dx      = new(big.Int)
        absDx   = new(big.Int)
        minDx   = new(big.Int).Abs(i)
        cube    = new(big.Int)
        fx      = new(big.Int)
        fxp     = new(big.Int)
        step    = new(big.Int)
    )
    for {
        cube.Exp(guess, n3, nil)
        dx.Sub(i, cube)
        cmp := dx.Cmp(n0)
        if cmp == 0 {
            return guess, n0
        }

        fx.Sub(cube, i)
        guessSq.Exp(guess, n2, nil)
        fxp.Mul(n3, guessSq)
        step.Div(fx, fxp)
        if step.Cmp(n0) == 0 {
            step.Set(n1)
        }

        absDx.Abs(dx)
        switch absDx.Cmp(minDx) {
        case -1:
            minDx.Set(absDx)
        case 0:
            return guess, dx
        }

        guess.Sub(guess, step)
    }
}
```

Surprisingly enough, the simple binary algorithm is also the fastest:

```
BenchmarkCbrt/binary/10e6-4       100000         19195 ns/op
BenchmarkCbrt/binary/10e12-4       30000         43634 ns/op
BenchmarkCbrt/binary/10e18-4       20000         73334 ns/op
BenchmarkCbrt/newton/10e6-4        30000         47027 ns/op
BenchmarkCbrt/newton/10e12-4       10000        123612 ns/op
BenchmarkCbrt/newton/10e18-4       10000        214884 ns/op
```

Here is the full code, including tests and benchmarks: https://play.golang.org/p/uoEmxRK5jgs.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it works out of the box. Thanks!